# Java Tables - Set editable columns and not editable

Tags: swing, jtable, imageicon, defaulttablemodel

I have a JTable with 2 columns.
The first column is to store ImageIcons and the second one to store a String.

I want to set the second column editable but not the first one.

Full code: https://pastebin.com/7qge1PVc

Here is a sample of my code:

```
File[] files = chooser.getSelectedFiles(); //Image files array
String[] columnNames = {"Image", "Description"};
Object[][] data = new Object[files.length][2]; //To fill with images and descriptions
int count = 0;

for(File imatge: files){
    if(accept(imatge)){
        imgBanknote = new ImageIcon( new ImageIcon(imatge.getAbsolutePath()).getImage().getScaledInstance(150, 120, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        data[count][0] = imgBanknote;
        data[count][1] = imatge;
        count++;
    }
}

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames){
    //  Returning the Class of each column will allow different
    //  renderers to be used based on Class
    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
        return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){
        return column != 0;
    }

};

taula.setModel(model); //Set model to JTable
taula.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(taula.getPreferredSize());
```

The problem is the `getColumnClass` method that I use to render the image, this make the second column not editable. I have no idea how to resolve.

Comment: Code looks reasonable. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. That is all you need is a table with 2 columns and add hard coded data to the table.

Comment: Here is the full JDialog code https://pastebin.com/7qge1PVc

Comment: You were not asked for the full code. You were asked for a [mcve]. The point of the MCVE is to simplify the problem. As I said where the data comes from is irrelevant, so the data can easily be hardcode to do a simple test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

The problem is `data[count][1] = imatge;`.
I was adding a File in the table, and a file in a JTable isn't editable.

To resolve the problem I've replaced `data[count][1] = imatge;` to `data[count][1] = imatge.getName();`, now it's a String and it's editable.